# Mod Rewrite - Changing Base URLS

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I got my mod-rewrite done correctly, however (obviously) the linked files on that page are wrong (cause they assume they're one directory inside).  Can I rewrite the the base url via mod rewrite for when that rewritecond is met?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to try [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) instead of mod_rewrite, because it has a feature ([`ProxyPassReverse`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse)) which is designed for this particular use-case.

Comment: Is there any other way with mod instead of the proxy pass?

Comment: You could take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580485/apache-mod-rewrite-and-multiple-domains) but mod_rewrite is really just a part of the URL resolution part of Apache, not the content generation part.